# Difference between type alias and using-declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, types, namespaces, typeid

Is there any difference between using a *type alias* and *alias template* on the one hand and *using-declaration* on the other hand defined as follows:

Given a class definition in a namespace scope:

```
namespace ns1
{
template< typename T >
struct A {};
}
```

And given another namespace, which introduces the `A` symbol by two different ways. First of them is *type alias* (*alias template*):

```
namespace ns2
{
template< typename T >
using A = ns1::A< T >; // match type-id
}
```

Second one is *using-declaration*:

```
namespace ns2
{
using ns1::A;
}
```

Is there any difference for ADL and for any other using contexts in `ns1` scope (reopened), in `ns2` scope or in outer scope?

Comment: For ADL n4527  [basic.lookup.argdep]/4.1 says any using directives are ignored